# Are there limitations to using Facebook Graph API if the fb account is newly created?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So basically I created a new fb account to use the fb graph api. I am able to create User access token but not provide it with necessary permissions, like in the dropdown menu 'Add a permission' in the 'Permissions' tab in the Graph API explorer, I am seeing only two permissions:'groups_show_list' and 'user_payment_tokens'. There should be more right, like publish_action or something. I want to post something through this account from another program, using the api.

I am also not able to generate a page access token. When I try to create it, it returns a page with 'something went wrong' message. Is this because of my account being new? What are the limitations caused by using a new account?

Comment: No, this should not have anything to do with how old the account is. (Duplicate accounts are against Facebook's ToS though, and especially for developing apps, you should use your one, own, personal account. If you get caught creating apps under "fake" accounts, you might lose access to them, if discovered.) The selection of available permissions might be dependent on what app _type_ you chose though - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app#step-2--choose-a-use-case

Comment: (`publish_actions` will certainly not be available though, that has been removed _ages_ ago. Publishing to a user timeline via API is not possible any more.)

Comment: Thank you . So what should I do instead of this? How can I post on my feed through another program automatically? What about page access token issue? Do you know why it might be showing the 'something went wrong' message?

Comment: No, I don't, because I don't know what exactly you did. _"When I try to create it"_ is a bit vague.